# Free UML 2 tool which generates C and C++ code

Tags: windows, gratis, uml

I am aware of [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39161/tools-to-generate-c-code-from-uml), however, I am explicitly requesting UML 2 support.

**Must have**

- free license, for commercial use
- support for class diagrams
- and message sequence charts
- and state diagrams
- code generation for C++
- Windows support

**Nice to have**

- other diagram types (especially use cases & activity)
- round trip editing
- code generation for C
- code generation for PHP
- the ability to draw diagrams from textual input (see, for instance [YUML](https://yuml.me/edit/10affcd2)).
- Linux support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but [BOUML](http://www.bouml.fr) looks like a good tool. It is quite well documented for a free tool.

Must haves:
free
class diagrams
communication, state and sequence diagrams
code generation for C++
Runs on Windows

Nice to haves:
Use case, activity, Object, component and deployment diagrams
C++ generator, reverse, roundtrip
C generator
PHP generator, reverse, roundtrip
runs under Linux

Extras:
Java generator, reverse, roundtrip
Python generator, reverse, roundtrip
Idl generator
MySQL generator, reverse
expandable via addons (plugouts)
addon (plugout) to generate C++ state machine from diagram

Comment: This looks very good. I think that I will use this for my Visual editing and code generation. I also asked about taking input from text files (so that I can code my own tools to generate these text files, then generate UML from them). That ought to have been a separate question.  If anyone reading this is interested, there can be no doubt that the answer is [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/)